# Keep row indices of DataFrame at Variance Threshold transformation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I'm doing a variance threshold feature selection with sklearn on a pandas DataFrame. In order to avoid a bias from feature selection - VarianceThreshold is only the first step - I've divided the original dataset into a part for feature selection (***X_selection***, ***y_selection***) and a part for modeling (***X_model***, ***y_model***). Nevertheless, they contain the same columns in the same order. So, I've started by defining the selector and fit the data afterwards:

```python
# get column names
X_columns = X_selection.columns

# doing the variance threshold feature selection
selector = VarianceThreshold()
selector.fit(X_selection)

# filtering the selected column names
X_columns = X_columns[selector.get_support()]

# transform original data according to selector
X_selection = pd.DataFrame(selector.transform(X_selection), columns = X_columns)
X_model = pd.DataFrame(selector.transform(X_model), columns = X_columns)
```

Unfortunately, I've encountered that the rows in the resulting ***X_selection*** and ***X_model*** are jumbled. For example, prior to the transformation I've got for some, exemplary rows out of ***X_model***:

```
        COL_X
0       0.000000
1       0.000000
2       0.000000
10      0.000000
25      0.185185
150     0.037037
3333    0.000000
16000   0.000000
```

After the transformation, calling the same row indices of ***X_model*** gives me:

```
        COL_X
0       0.000000
1       0.000000
2       0.111111
10      0.000000
25      0.000000
150     0.000000
3333    0.000000
16000   0.111111
```

In my understanding *transform* has shuffled the rows in a for me unknown manner. Though the relations to the ***y_model*** array with class labels is broken, because the order of rows is unchanged here. Thank you for any comments how to fix it or where my mistakes are hidden.

Comment: Does `X_selection = selector.fit_transform(X_selection)` and `X_model = selector.transform(X_model)` also gives you the same problem? I would guess the columns are not being picked up correctly than the rows

Comment: Yes, it's exactly the same result, the COL_X values have changed.

Comment: Am unable to reproduce this issue, can you share sample `X_selection` and `X_model` dataframes?

Comment: I've tried to produce sample data frames, while encoutering the probable cause of this issue. Making the transformed X_model again a DataFrame just reindexed the DataFrame. Therefore, my call on some indices is misleading. I think the order of the rows is retained, the rows has simply another "name" now. I figure it out and post a solution afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact I wasn't aware of is that pandas assigns new indices (starting with 0, increment 1) to the DataFrame when converting the resulting array of transform to a pandas DataFrame again:

```python
X_model = pd.DataFrame(selector.transform(X_model), columns = X_columns)
```

When asking for a subset of rows with the "old" row indices, this gives other values than before. So, the sequence is still the same. However, I would like to preserve the original row indices. Therefore, I now set the indices according to the old indices still preserved in ***y_model***.

```
X_model = X_model.set_index(y_model.index)
```